# 3 levels of dimension qualification in an mdx query on a multidimensional cube - why

Tags: ssas

In the example of a customer by sales MDX query shown below, can someone explain why customer is qualified to 3 levels?
[image]

Comment: I'm getting a forum standards violation when I paste the URL in the original post, so I'm taking the liberty of trying to record it here  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710387/Learn-to-Write-Custom-MDX-Query-First-Time